# ESP8266 wifi server to android client

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, bufferedinputstream, esp8266

Ive been trying to setup a server using ESP8266 wifi module on a particular port. I'm done with that.

I want to receive the message from it now.
Whenever I connect using socket.connect(), I am able to detect it in the esp8266. But I cant receive any message, the server sends through the same socket.

I am trying to obtain the message using DataInputStream inside a while loop continuously in a  async task.Pls let me know if my approach or code is wrong! Thanks!

This is my code:

```
    package test.espclient;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
//import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textResponse;
    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear,buttonDiscon , buttonSendMsg;

    EditText welcomeMsg;

    Socket socket;

    boolean socketStatus = false;

    MyClientTask myClientTask;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        buttonDiscon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeSocket);
        buttonSendMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMsg);
        textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

        welcomeMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.welcomemsg);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

        buttonDiscon.setOnClickListener(buttonDisconnectOnCLickListener);

        //buttonSendMsg.setOnClickListener(sendMessage);

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textResponse.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
      if(socketStatus)
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Already talking to a Socket!! Disconnect and try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      else {
          socket = null;
          String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString();
          int port = Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString());
          String tMsg = welcomeMsg.getText().toString();

          if (address == null || port == 0)
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter valid address/port", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          else {
                           myClientTask = new MyClientTask(address,port,tMsg);
                          myClientTask.execute();

          } //else when no active socket conn. and credentials are validated.


      } //else when already active socket conn.
        }
    };

    OnClickListener buttonDisconnectOnCLickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!socketStatus)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SOCKET Already Closed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                try {
                    onDisconnect();
                    if(myClientTask.isCancelled()) {
                        socket.close();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Socket Closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        socketStatus = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Couldn't Disconnect! Pls try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        socketStatus = true;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    };

//    OnClickListener sendMessage = new OnClickListener() {
//        @Override
//        public void onClick(View v) {
//            String msg = welcomeMsg.toString();
//            if(msg.equals(""))
//            {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message is empty!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//            else if(!socketStatus)
//            {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Establish Socket Connection first!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//            else
//            {
//                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(editTextAddress
//                    .getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPort
//                    .getText().toString()),
//                    msg);
//            myClientTask.execute();
//
//            }
//
//        }
//    };

    public void onDisconnect()
    {
        myClientTask.cancel(true);
    }

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response ="";
        String msgToServer;

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port, String msgTo) {
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
            msgToServer = msgTo;
            Log.w("MSG","Entering async task");
        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


          //  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                socketStatus = true;

               // dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

//                if(msgToServer != null){
//                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToServer);
//                }
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
                socketStatus = false;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }

            Log.w("MSG","Inside while loop for retrieving data");
           while(!isCancelled()){
               try {
                   dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                   response = dataInputStream.readUTF();

                   if(!response.isEmpty())
                   {
                       publishProgress(response);
                       Log.w("Data:",response);
                   }

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }


//                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
//                    try {
//                        dataOutputStream.close();
//                    } catch (IOException e) {
//                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    }
//                }

                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            try {
                Log.w("MSG","Stopping async task");
                socket.close();
                socketStatus = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                socketStatus = true;
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            textResponse.setText(values[0]);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Server:"+values[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.w("MSG","Updating with msg");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.w("MSG","On postExecute method..");
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE(16-12-15)** I made the following changes under the doInBackground().
originally, I used DataInputStream, now I replaced it with BufferedReader.
The change was made under the while loop part for constantly checking the socket input stream. Also added the ESP8266 code for reference.

Now I able to Receive the text sent from ESP8266, but it reaches only after I send 3 or 4 messages via CIPSEND cmd. for e.g. if i send "hi", "hello" "yo", after sending the third word, I receive all the words together as "hihelloyo"
Instead of recieving each message as soon as it is sent, I receive it very late.
I am not sure what exactly is causing this problem. May be the buffer size?
How to solve this ?

**MODIFIED CODE**:

```
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


          //  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
          //  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                socketStatus = true;
               // dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

//                if(msgToServer != null){
//                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToServer);
//                }
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
                socketStatus = false;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }


            Log.w("MSG","Inside while loop for retrieving data");

            while(!isCancelled() && socketStatus) {
                try {
//                  dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
//                      response = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    response = br.readLine();
                    if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                        publishProgress(response);
                        Log.w("Data:", response);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

**ESP266 code**

```
    #include <AltSoftSerial.h>
AltSoftSerial ESP8266 ;//(8,9)|Rx,Tx

int LED = 13;

boolean FAIL_8266 = false;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 128
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

String ssid="\"SSID\"";
String pass="\"PASSWORD\"";

void clearESP8266SerialBuffer()
{
  Serial.println("= clearESP8266SerialBuffer() =");
  while (ESP8266.available() > 0) {
    char a = ESP8266.read();
    Serial.write(a);
  }
  Serial.println("==============================");
}



void sendHTTPResponse(int id, String content)
{
  String response;
  response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
  response += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; 
  response += "Content-Length: ";
  response += content.length();
  response += "\r\n";
  response +="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
  response += content;

  String cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  cmd += id;
  cmd += ",";
  cmd += response.length();

  Serial.println("--- AT+CIPSEND ---");
  sendESP8266Cmdln(cmd, 1000);

  Serial.println("--- data ---");
  sendESP8266Data(response, 1000);
}

boolean waitOKfromESP8266(int timeout)
{
  do{
    Serial.println("wait OK...");
    delay(1000);
    if(ESP8266.find("OK"))
    {
      return true;
    }

  }while((timeout--)>0);
  return false;
}

//Send command to ESP8266, assume OK, no error check
//wait some time and display respond
void sendESP8266Cmdln(String cmd, int waitTime)
{
  ESP8266.println(cmd);
  delay(waitTime);
  clearESP8266SerialBuffer();
}

//Basically same as sendESP8266Cmdln()
//But call ESP8266.print() instead of call ESP8266.println()
void sendESP8266Data(String data, int waitTime)
{
  ESP8266.print(data);
  delay(waitTime);
  clearESP8266SerialBuffer();
}

void adc()
{
  int ldr;

  for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
  {
    ldr = analogRead(A0); 
    sendESP8266Cmdln("AT+CIPSEND=0,5",1000);
    sendESP8266Cmdln(String(ldr),1000); 
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);

  do{
  ESP8266.println("AT+RST");
    delay(1000);
    if(ESP8266.find("Ready"))
    {
      Serial.println("Module is ready");
      delay(1000);
      clearESP8266SerialBuffer();

      sendESP8266Cmdln("AT+CWMODE=1",1000);

      //Join Wifi network
      sendESP8266Cmdln("AT+CWJAP="+ssid+","+pass,6500);

      //Get and display my IP
      sendESP8266Cmdln("AT+CIFSR", 1000);  

      //Set multi connections
      sendESP8266Cmdln("AT+CIPMUX=1", 1000);
      //Setup web server on port 80
      sendESP8266Cmdln("AT+CIPSERVER=1,3333",1000);

      Serial.println("Server setup finish");

      FAIL_8266 = false;
    }else{
      Serial.println("Module have no response.");
      delay(500);
      FAIL_8266 = true;
    }
  }while(FAIL_8266);

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  ESP8266.setTimeout(1000);
}
void loop() {

  // listen for communication from the ESP8266 and then write it to the serial monitor

     if(ESP8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {
    String msg = ESP8266.readString();

    if(msg.substring(0,4)=="Link")
    Serial.println("Client connected!");

    else if(msg.substring(0,6)=="Unlink")
    Serial.println("Client Disconncected!!");


      else if(msg.substring(1,5)=="+IP")
      {
        Serial.println("Client says: "+msg.substring(9,14));
      }

      else
      {
       // Serial.println("Calling ADC.!");
        //adc();

       // Serial.println("Msg:"+msg.charAt(0)+msg.charAt(1)+msg.charAt(2)+msg.charAt(3));
       // Serial.println("Something recieved!: "+msg.substring(1,2));
        Serial.println("MSG:"+msg);  
      }
  } 

    // listen for user input and send it to the ESP8266
    if ( Serial.available() )       {  ESP8266.write( Serial.read() );  }
  }


//Clear and display Serial Buffer for ESP8266
```

**UPDATE(17-12-15):Added pics for reference**
My arduino serial window showing the AT+CIPSEND commands.
[image: My arduino serial window, showing the AT+CIPSEND commands]

pic of the app running on phone.
[image: from my app running on phone]

Comment: It will be very useful to see some of the code for the esp8266. Also, what error are you getting on your java code? Exception? Timeout?

Comment: I am not getting any errors on my logcat. Initially if i used Datainputstream, I did not recieve anything. Now, i changed it to bufferedReader. however, I receive msg only after sending minimum 9 characters from ESP8266, using AT+CIPSEND command. Otherwise, the previously sent shorter msgs, come all together, like Ive mentioned above in the post.

Comment: Now I noticed its not, just 9 characters, the minimum no.of characters to be sent before it shows up in the android, keeps varying. today, it was about 14 characters. Does it have anything to do with the buffer size of the buffered reader? I dont think, the problem is with esp8266, because, i tested it out with a telnet android app. I can receive all small words like "Hi", "hello" immediately.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting the code of the ESP8266. I'm gonna take a chance on this as I can't test your java side. You have the following line on the JAVA code:  response = br.readLine(); but on the ESP8266 I don't see you are actually sending the end of the line, are you entering the text you want to send with the keyboard and hoping this will be transmitted to the JAVA side? Try actually adding the end of line to your code and try again.

Comment: I've added two pics for ur reference. I dont think attaching "\n" with the command was necessary as the serial window's line ending was already set to "Both NL and CR". But Still i tried like, AT+CIPSEND=0,5, foll.by "hi\n", I still get delayed response at the app. As you can see, from the pics, I receive the \n character also on the java side.

Comment: Btw, I tried changing the baud rate from 9600 to 115200, uprading the firmware , all had no impact. Also fyi, my hw setup consists of an arduino uno whose connected to the esp module. I have coded the arduino initially to setup the esp as a server, and after that, it runs the void loop, where it continuously listens for many manual commands to be sent to the esp from the serial window of the arduino. thats when i send my at+cipsend commands.

Comment: Sorry but change the readLine JAVA line to read, that will print every single character you send. The new lone, carriage return doesn't always is setup the same way (it could be the other way around), please, just try it before we keep going.

Comment: Also, I don't see the count for the extra NL & CR characters on the AT+CIPSEND , If you send 2 chars you need to send 0,4 (your 2 chars plus the carriage return and the line feed chars).

Comment: On esp side, close the connection after sending response.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5, I tried to read character by character as u suggested using this code:StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                    int read;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    while( (read = br.read())!=-1)
                    {
                        msg.append((char)read);
                    }
                    response = msg.toString();
But still not getting any proper response.

Comment: Also, I know, I tried sending like cipsend=0,4 foll.by hi\r\n, but later, I get the message in android as hi\r\n, not "hi".

Comment: @Mert, yeah! it worked! I can get the messages immediately irrespective of their lengths, after i close the connection on esp side using cipclose=0. But is this is the only way? Is it possible to make the device and the app talk? How come it is possible in the telnet application, where i can continuously send data till i close connection on one side.?

Comment: @ShankarS I've posted an answer. You can check. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to this comment:

> ... it worked! I can get the messages immediately irrespective of their lengths, after i close the connection on esp side using cipclose=0. But is this is the only way? Is it possible to make the device and the app talk? How come it is possible in the telnet application, where i can continuously send data till i close connection on one side.?

On the upper application layers data from TCPIP connection is presented as a Stream. Using this stream with well-defined application protocols like HTTP or telnet, message exchange is defined. In your case basically Android side does not know what amount of data to receive. After using buffered reader you get buffered answer, not the whole.

In telnet protocol for example there are control commands. Thus the system goes on working.

To solve your case:

1. Close connection after every message. (this slows down things)
2. Implement a basic application protocol. For example: Implement a Message frame:

```
FRAME
1st byte         : length ( this byte gives the length of the payload )
2nd...255th byte : payload ( this is the actual message )

LOGIC
-Sender packs the frame giving length and payload.
-Sender sends the data
...
-Receiver queries for the available bytes. 
-When available bytes are >1 receive only 1 byte say it is 'n'
-'n' is the length of the total frame
-Read 'n' bytes from the stream. if EOF then return what is received.
```

In addition to this you can implement control commands. 
For example you may want the receiver to close the connection so your frame can be:

```
Byte 1 : length
Byte 2 : command (0=nothing, 1=close conn)
Byte 3..n : payload

LOGIC
-When receiver finished receiving and command is 1 then closes the connection.
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by control commands? can you throw me some examples?